# WSO2 CEP 4.1.0 - JMS event receiver stops dequeing messages

Tags: events, wso2, jms, activemq-classic, complex-event-processing

I created a JMS event receiver to dequeue messages from a JMS queue (ActiveMQ 5.14.1) and insert the messages/events in a event stream. In the periods that a small number of events are received all works fine, however, in the high peak period, when more then 150k events are received by hour,  the queue receiver stops dequeing JMS messages. After a restart of WSO2 CEP a few thousands are dequeued and then it stops dequeuing again. No error appears in the log files.
Has anyone experienced this behaviour?

Thank you.
Hugo Calado